# Сборка кластера из пк

Tags: кластер, железо, linux

Всем привет, посоветуйте материалы по сборке небольшого кластера из 2х пк. Для параллельных вычислений на cuda и mpi. Может какие рекомендации будет по-поводу железа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кое что уже было, может [подойдет](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/298/ubuntu-cloud)